# Return Entity object or POJO to UI?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo

I have JPA `Employee` persistent entity wjich has 50 fields.  Sometimes I need to display all 50 fields to UI or sometime much less than that.

There are two approaches I can think of

**Approach 1:-**

I will continue return the `Employee` entity to UI. There are ways(with annotation) where I can mention which specific fields under `Employee` needs to be returned

**Example :-**

If I want to ignore `MiddleName` from Employee class before returning json to browser, I will create `EmployeeMixin` with required `@JsonIgnoreProperties` like below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"MiddleName"})
public abstract class EmployeeMixin extends Employee{

}




Employee employee = new Employee ();
Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> mixinMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
mixinMap.put(Employee.class, EmployeeMixin.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(mixinMap);
return mapper.writeValueAsString(employee);
```

**Approach 2:-**

I will make new POJO containing again all 5o fields and retuen to UI.

My question is  which is better design approach ? Should  I return Entity object or new Pojo object(constructed from Entity) to UI ?

Comment: As of me approach 1 is good. because creating new pojo with same fields is meaning less.
so use approach 1 and return only required fields by using annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer **Approach 3**, projection

- Create a `DTO` object for each case with a variable set of fields you need.
- Create a corresponding `JPQL` or `CriteriaQuery`to populate appropriate `DTO`.

Having an `entity` like

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class Pojo3 {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   @Setter
   private String f1, f2,f3;
}
```

you can make a `DTO` class with subset of fields like

```
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor // Pojo2DTO(id,f1,f2)
public class Pojo2DTO {
   private Long id;
   private String f1,f2;
}
```

that can be populated in `JPQL` like this test shows

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test() {
   Pojo3 pojo3 = new Pojo3();
   pojo3.setF1("f1");
   pojo3.setF2("f2");
   pojo3.setF3("f3");      
   em.persist(pojo3);

   // **NOTE** the full package path to DTO object
   TypedQuery<Pojo2DTO> tq = em.createQuery(
         "SELECT NEW org.example.jpa.manyfields.Pojo2DTO(p3.id, p3.f1, p3.f2) "
      + " FROM Pojo3 p3 WHERE p3.id=:id", Pojo2DTO.class);
   tq.setParameter("id", pojo3.getId());

   Pojo2DTO pojo2dto = tq.getSingleResult(); 
   log.info("{}, {}, {}", pojo2dto.getId(), pojo2dto.getF1(), pojo2dto.getF2());

}
```

Comment: But whats wrong with approach_1 ?. With approach_3 i need to create multiple DTO specific to each requirement

Comment: @user3198603 If I understood correctly you would annotate entity fields in A1. So I am not sure how you would annotate entity for each requirement separately? A3 would leave the entity itself intact. But if I misunderstood can you provide a simple example how you would do the annotation in A1?

Comment: @user3198603 Seeing your example I think this depends on the case. What if you want to ignore 49 fields? And somewhere in between ignoring 20-40 fields it might be only a matter of taste. But anyway you will actually create DTOs (so with different annotations) in A1 also. The only difference i can see is that you always query the whole entity but ignore fields in JSON serialization which might not be big deal anyway. UNLESS you start using this method for big lists.